# how to convert list of list to string format (unable to find a way to extract the elements in List of list to a string)

Tags: python, list

I would like to convert the following list: `x = [[a,b,c,d],[c,d,e,f]]`

to `'abcdcdef'`

thanks for your help

Comment: Just flatten the list and use [`join()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.join): `''.join(n for l in x for n in l)`

Answer (score 1):

Do like this:

```
[ item for innerlist in outerlist for item in innerlist ]
```

Turning that directly into a string with separators:

```
','.join(str(item) for innerlist in outerlist for item in innerlist)
```

Yes, the order of 'for innerlist in outerlist' and 'for item in innerlist' is correct. Even though the "body" of the loop is at the start of the listcomp, the order of nested loops (and 'if' clauses) is still the same as when you would write the loop out:

```
for innerlist in outerlist:
for item in innerlist:
    ...
```

Comment: Hi Billions.A.Joel, thanks for your help.
appreciate it

Comment: You are welcome. You can mark the question as correct to help someone else too.